# Проблема с выводом значения хэш функции в python

Tags: python, хеширование

Мне нужно вывести хэш строки (пример - '5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8' )
Для этого я написал данную программу

```
    import hashlib
    a2=' 222222'
    a2=a2.encode('utf-8')
    print(a2)
    he1=hashlib.sha512(a2)
    print("he1= ",he1)
    he1.hexdigest()
    print("he1= ",he1)
```

А на выходе я получаю такой результат

```
b' 222222'
he1=  <sha512 HASH object @ 0x01534840>
he1=  <sha512 HASH object @ 0x01534840>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так надо:

```
import hashlib
s = ' 222222'
byte_s = s.encode('utf-8')
print('byte_s: <{}>'.format(byte_s))
hash_sha512 = hashlib.sha512(byte_s)
hash_sha512_hexdigest = hash_sha512.hexdigest()
print('hash_sha512_hexdigest: <{}>'.format(hash_sha512_hexdigest))
```